# form tag default behavior

Tags: html, reactjs

When I click the POST button in CreatePost.js, submission fails with 404 error code but it works fine when I click the LOG IN button in LoginModal.js. Form submission works well when I take e.preventDefault() line out in handleSubmit() function in CraetePost.js but I don't want it to direct to other page after submission. I don't know why submission fails when the codes in the both files are almost same.

CreatePost.js

```
const CreatePost = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("/sumbit", {
        title: title,
        content: content,
      })
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="create-post-container">
      <div className="create-post-left-container">
        <p>Create a post</p>
        <hr />
        <div className="post-container">
          <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              placeholder="Title"
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <textarea
              id="content"
              name="content"
              placeholder="Text(optional)"
              onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" className="post-button" color="primary">
              POST
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <CommunityBanner className="create-post-community-banner" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

LoginModal.js

```
const LoginModal = ({ updateToken }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
    username_error: "",
    password_error: "",
  });

  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const isValid = formValidate();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isValid) {
      axios
        .post("/login", {
          username: username,
          password: password,
        })
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .then((data) => {
          if ("error_message" in data) {
            setErrors((prev) => ({
              ...prev,
              ["password_error"]: data.error_message,
            }));
          } else {
            toggle();
            localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem("username", data.username);
            updateToken();
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          toggle();
          alert("Sign up failed. Please try again");
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };

 return (
    <div>
      <Button
        className="nav-button login-button"
        color="link"
        onClick={() => {
          toggle();
          setErrors({});
        }}
      >
        LOG IN
      </Button>

      <Modal className="auth-modal" isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader className="modal-header" toggle={toggle}>
          Log in
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody className="modal-body">
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId="1087910724182-02v9tf6jm6h867i3vd81rui2dm4b6jvb.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <Button
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                color="link"
                className="google-button"
              >
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
                CONTINUE WITH GOOGLE
              </Button>
            )}
            onSuccess={googleOnSuccess}
            onFailure={googleOnFailure}
            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
          />
          <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <div className="input-buttons-wrapper">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="USERNAME"
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <div className="error-message">{errors["username_error"]}</div>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="PASSWORD"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <div className="error-message">{errors["password_error"]}</div>
            </div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              className="modal-login-button"
              color="primary"
            >
              LOG IN
            </Button>
          </form>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Note that the URL you are POSTing to is "sumbit", not "submit"...

Comment: oh stupid mistake. Thanks